# What is the easiest way to export a SQLServer 2000 database to XML?

Tags: sql-server, xml, export, data-transfer

I have an old SQL Server 2000 database that I want to get into XML so I can from there import parts of it into an SQLite database for a PHP website.

I've accessed the SQL Server 2000 database via **SQL Server Management Studio 2008 Express**, I can open all the tables, view the data, etc.

I was expecting to be able to e.g. **right-click** on "Tables" and select "Export all tables to XML" but cannot find any **export feature** like this.

**What is the easiest way to export this SQL Server database to XML files, I don't even need the schema (int, varchar, etc.), just the data.**

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM {tablename} FOR XML AUTO
```

is working fine in this particular case, thanks ogiboho via twitter

Answer (score 1):

You could write a .NET app that retrieves the tables to a dataset and then get the XML from the dataset...

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zx8h06sz.aspx

Alternatively you could look at this forum post, it has lots of different ways to approach achieving this...

http://sqlxml.org/faqs.aspx?faq=29